# Running DepthEstimationPipeline example from huggingface.co

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

getting the following error when running

```
depth_estimator = pipeline(task="depth-estimation", model="LiheYoung/depth-anything-base-hf")
```

> ValueError: The checkpoint you are trying to load has model type
> `depth_anything` but Transformers does not recognize this
> architecture. This could be because of an issue with the checkpoint,
> or because your version of Transformers is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that work for me is from [here](https://huggingface.co/LiheYoung/depth-anything-large-hf/discussions/1)

Just install transformers from source by:

```
pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
```

instead (Quick tour recommendation):

```
!pip install transformers datasets
```

additionally you may need to install PIL by:

```
pip install pillow
```